Confusion in strong law of large numbers

This is a screenshot from Probability Theory Achim Klenke Chapter 5. The last line says that for fixed $\omega$, but if I take $\omega$ to be a constant sequence, say $6$, I get the result as $6$. I am sure that I am missing something very basic, but I am not able to figure it out.

Indeed, the SLLN tells that $S_n(\omega)/n \to \mathbb{E}[X_1]$ for almost every $\omega$, in the sense that $$\mathbb{P}(S_n/n \to \mathbb{E}[X_1]) = 1.$$ Equivalently, the set of all $\omega$'s for which the convergence to the mean fails comprise a zero-probability event.

The phrase "for fixed $\omega$" ordinarily means "for any fixed $\omega$", and you're right that this meaning makes the last sentence false. I think the author probably meant "for certain fixed $\omega$", to be followed by an explanation that these certain $\omega$'s are in fact almost all $\omega$'s.

Thank you,I understand it now
